# How does one remove all event listeners within a function for multiple function calls?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is part of the code I am currently working on. In my `newDrag` function, I set an initial `addEventListener()` whenever my mouse is moved.

```js
function newDrag(id) {
   document.addEventListener("mousemove", consoleLog, true);
      function consoleLog() {
        console.log(id);
      }
    
   document.onmousedown = function () {
        console.log("downed")
        window.document.removeEventListener("mousemove", consoleLog, true);
    };
}
    
newDrag("div2");
newDrag("div0");
```

As the function is called, the output given is `div2` and `div0`. However, when I click the mouse and start moving my cursor again, I keep getting an output of `div2`.

KEEP IN MIND: For the disabling function, the mousedown HAS to occur in document. The code does work when the element is called, but I need it to be in document.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach the event handlers to the elements (`#div0` or `#div2`) instead of the document. Then use the `target` property of the event object.

```js
function newDrag(id) {
  document.querySelector(`#${id}`).addEventListener("mousemove", consoleLog, true);
  function consoleLog(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
  }

  document.querySelector(`#${id}`).onmousedown = function (e) {
    console.log("downed")
    e.target.removeEventListener("mousemove", consoleLog, true);
  };
}

newDrag("div2");
newDrag("div0");
```

```css
div[id^=div]{
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.4);
  margin: 20px;
}

/* for the snippet console */
.as-console-wrapper{
  max-height: 1.2em !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="div0">div0</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set up a different mouse event listener for each element. Set one up on `document`, then check the [$event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to see which element you're hovering over.

That way you can remove the listener the way you want to.

To get the element ID, use `$event.target.id`

```js
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", consoleLog);

  function consoleLog(e) {
    if (['div0', 'div2'].includes(e.target.id)) console.log(e.target.id);
  }

  document.onmousedown = function(e) {
    console.log("downed", e.target.id)
   document.removeEventListener("mousemove", consoleLog);
  };
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 10px;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="div0"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Also helped me with my issue :D